# Translate arguments of a user added custom code

Tags: translation, localization, plugin-wpml

I needed to hardcode some extra code to a existing portfolio-template. Now there are two arguments which values need to be translated:

```
<a href="/news/" class="hover-on">

  <div class="hoverdiv-feat hide-for-small">
        <img src="location" class="attachment-portfolio-feat wp-post-image" alt="uudised"></div>    
   <div class="overlay hover-on">

     <h4>News</h4>

   </div><!-- END .overlay -->      
    <div class="no-hoverdiv-feat show-for-small">
        <img width="299" height="227" src="location" class="attachment-portfolio-feat wp-post-image" alt="uudised"></div>

</a>
```

precisely  `href` value `/news/` and `News` between `<h4>` tags.

I'm using WPML to translate the rest of the sites content but I cannot get these values to appear in the **string translation** admin area. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is this pure html or php. The strings look diffirent for html and php.

Comment: One other thing, why do you want to translate `href` and what do you want to translate in `href`

Comment: I need to change `href` value of `/news/` into `/новости/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are hardcoding the link, you will need to use [icl_link_to_element()](http://wpml.org/documentation/support/creating-multilingual-wordpress-themes/hard-coded-theme-links/) function and wrap any text you want to translate inside a gettext function:

```
<?php icl_link_to_element( 'ID_of_your_news_page', 'page', '<h4>' . __('News') . '</h4>' ); ?>
```

This way you will get the correct version of the link based on the current language with the text translated. If you want translate the slug you have to do it in the [page/post edit screen](http://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/translating-page-slugs/).

After you have edited the code in your question, I think it is better to use [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) and [icl_object_id()](http://wpml.org/documentation/support/creating-multilingual-wordpress-themes/language-dependent-ids/#2). As I said before, [you should wrap any text in your theme inside a gettext function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Localization_Technology) in order to be translatable. For the href value, first you have to create the two versions of the news page and translate the slug for the two versions (/news/ and /новости/) and then:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( icl_object_id( ID_of_news_page, 'page', true, ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) ); ?>" class="hover-on">

  <div class="hoverdiv-feat hide-for-small">
        <img src="location" class="attachment-portfolio-feat wp-post-image" alt="uudised"></div>    
   <div class="overlay hover-on">

     <h4><?php _e('News'); ?></h4>

   </div><!-- END .overlay -->      
    <div class="no-hoverdiv-feat show-for-small">
        <img width="299" height="227" src="location" class="attachment-portfolio-feat wp-post-image" alt="uudised"></div>

</a>
```

Comment: Well it actually is just a link to a news page. No categories for the news, neither will there be any in the future.

Comment: I've edited the answer to get the page's link

Comment: The code works but for some reason they are not showing up in the string translation admin area. Where to look?

Comment: What do you expect to find in the translation admin area? With the above code only the "News" string was added to translatable string that you should be in the translation admin area of WPML. For the slug of the URL, as I said, you have to translate manually the slug of each version of the page. See referenes linked in the answer.

Comment: Not seeing any "News" string added to the translation admin area of WPML. But as long as I can construct a function responsible of changing the texts when language codes change, my goal will be achieved.